# jQuery UI Tabs- Losing focus changes styles

Tags: jquery, css, tabs

So, I'm using jQuery UI tabs here: http://cjsheatingandair.com

When the page first loads the active tab does not have it's anchor in focus. Clicking another tab causes that tab to be activated. Then when you click somewhere else on the page, the tab stays activated but the anchor text loses focus and changes style.

Is there a way to link the focus and active tab so that the user can click other places in the windows and not lose the focus style? Or maybe remove the focusing all together?

Comment: NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://cjsheatingandair.com/resources/demos/style.css" and what language is "When the page first loads the active tab does not have it's a active." ??  suggest you download firebug for firefox or start using developer tools in Chrome.  You can see how the elements are called out dynamically as you move the mouse around the site.  You can also see loading / javascript errors.

Comment: The anchor thing seems very sound to me.. the only thing that I can see is off is the font color of the selected tab when first selected.  Its barely visible.  Looks much better after you click anywhere else on the page.  Probably should fix that in CSS (or maybe you already have, we just can't see it because your demos/style.css file isn't getting loaded..)  Ouch.  Is this a wordpress site?  Why oh Why aren't you using a Child Theme?  Takes about 7 or 8 minutes to learn saves hours and hours later...

Comment: Sorry. I've done a little more digging and realized I was using the wrong terminology. I've edited it now. I AM using a child theme and yes it is wordpress, but the jQuery tabs are just coded in. I've been using developer tools and I can see now that "focus" is what's causing my problem. .ui-state-focus to be exact. Is there a way to remove focusing all together?

Comment: I just checked, and the site looks very good now.. the only thing.. before when you clicked on a menu select, the top url didn't change.. now it changes to the complete anchor link.  That's not a problem, per se a this point but could be a concern if you have nested menu selections (submenus)...   If you are only going one layer deep on menus what you have seems good to me.  And do realize, with a child theme all of your work is done there in the file style.css.  You have to learn how to 'trump' other CSS callouts with CSS Specificity. http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

Comment: Thanks! Yeah I totally ditched jQuery UI and just went with straight Javascript tabs that I found here on StackOverflow

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up using http://jsfiddle.net/BJ8vZ/ Thanks Atul Gupta

```
<style>
#tabs {border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;height:33px;margin:0 0 10px;padding-top:5px;background:#eee;}
#tabs a {float:left;margin-left:2px;border-radius:3px 3px 0 0;border:1px solid #eee;border-bottom-color:#ccc;color:#08c;height:32px;line-height:32px;padding:0 12px;text-decoration:none;}
#tabs a:hover {background:#ddd;color:#058;border-color:#ddd #ddd #ccc;}
#tabs a.active {background:#fff;color:#555;border-color:#ccc #ccc #fff;}
#tabs a.active:hover {background:#fff;color:#555;border-color:#ccc #ccc #fff;}
#tabs_data fieldset {display:none;border:0;}
#tabs_data fieldset div {font-size:13px;}
</style>
<div id="tabs">
<a href="#" onclick="tab_click(0);">tab 1</a>
<a href="#" onclick="tab_click(1);">tab 2</a>
<a href="#" onclick="tab_click(2);">tab 3</a>
</div>
<div id="tabs_data">
<fieldset> contents of tab 1</fieldset>
<fieldset> contents of tab 2</fieldset>
<fieldset> contents of tab 3</fieldset>
</div>
<script>
var tabActive=1, tabs=document.getElementById('tabs').getElementsByTagName('A'), tabs_data=document.getElementById('tabs_data').getElementsByTagName('fieldset');
function tab_click(x){
    if(x > -1 && x < tabs.length && x < tabs_data.length){
        tabs[tabActive].setAttribute('class','');
        tabs_data[tabActive].style.display='none';
        tabActive=x;
        tabs[tabActive].setAttribute('class','active');
        tabs_data[tabActive].style.display='block';
    } return false;
}tab_click(0);
document.onkeydown=function (evnt){ 
    if(evnt.keyCode==37 || evnt.keyCode==39) 
    tab_click(tabActive+evnt.keyCode-38); 
}
</script>
```